# Request for resources or techniques for bounding the infinity norm of an infinite product convolved with a simple function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm attempting to bound an expression of the form.
$$
\lVert(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \phi_i) * s \rVert_{\infty}
$$

Where $\phi_i$ are bounded periodic step functions which can be replaced by smoothed versions if need be, and for any sufficiently large integer n,  $\exists m$ such that $i \geq m$ implies $\phi_i(x) = 1$ for $x \in (-n, n).$

Young's convolution inequality is clearly insufficient. I  also attempted to deal with the problem using the Fourier transform as I have a nice closed form solution to the Fourier transform of $\phi_i$ and $s$.

I'm trying to get a sense for the standard techniques and references that would be applicable to this problem generally, and any lesser known results that could be useful.

p.s. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Edit: In particular I'm trying to bound this by a constant, and $\phi_i(x) =  1 - f_i(x)$

$$f_i(x) =  \begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{if the nearest integer of $x$ has property $p_i$} \\
                                   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}$$

$p_i$ is normally a divisibility criteria such as $p |n \text{ and }  p^k \nmid n.$

Note: Most of the formulation of the problem is up in the air, and as such i'm not really looking for a particular solution but techniques to bound this type of convolution generally.

Comment: As written, it is not even clear whether it is a product of convolutions or a convolution of the product. In general, if you want something better than wild guesses about what might work, post *all* details (what exactly the functions are, what bound you would consider satisfactory, etc.). Then someone will think of it :-)